# Black and white plot with corrplot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am doing a bachelor thesis where we want to plot the precision matrix to help visualize genome connections. The problem is that some values are large and most values are small and it is hard to see the smallest values. So I wanted to make it either a connection or not a connections, that is an adjacency matrix and plot this instead.

This was possible to to with GGplot but I want I also want to be able to use it with multiple plots in one plot-windows using par so that I can plot it with other plot functions (like igraph for example).

To make the example reproducible I use a code where I generate a random matrix. I have found that corrplot can but I was wondering if it is possible to make it entirely black and white? This is the example code.

```
matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.5),10,10)

corrplot(adj_org, is.corr = FALSE, method = "color",
         col=c("Black","White"),tl.pos = "n")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited the question to focus more on the visualization part and less on the programming side of it.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bit of a hack, but it should do what you want. corrplot is ignoring the first color in your list for some reason.

```
adj_org = matrix(rbinom(100,1,0.5),10,10)
corrplot(adj_org, is.corr = FALSE, method = "color", col=c("#F0F0F0", "Black", "White"),tl.pos = "n")
```